# mysql select result based on multiple matching criteria of 2 or more columns

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

My table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE candidate_tbl  (
  `name` VARCHAR(1),
  `degree` VARCHAR(41),
  `doneMasters` VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO candidate_tbl 
  (`name`, `degree`, `doneMasters`)
VALUES
  ('A', 'MBA', 'true'),
  ('A', 'MS', 'false'),
  ('B', 'MBA', 'true'),
  ('B', 'MS', 'true'),
  ('C', 'MBA', 'false'),
  ('C', 'MS', 'false'),
  ('D', 'MBA', 'false'),
  ('D', 'MS','true'),
  ('E', 'MBA', 'false'),
  ('E', 'MS', 'false'),
  ('F', 'MBA', 'false'),
  ('F', 'MS', 'true'),
  ('G', 'MBA', 'false'),
  ('G', 'MS', 'false'),
  ('H', 'MS', 'true'),
  ('H', 'MS', 'true');
```

I want the list of candidates who neither has MS nor MBA, which is C,E and G

I tried these 4 ways, Fiddle given [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b13595b83eea855657eda3935a6304ab)

**Method-1**

```
SELECT name,count(*) FROM candidate_tbl
WHERE doneMasters = 'false'
AND doneMasters = 'false'
GROUP BY name
HAVING count(*) = 2;
```

**Method-2**

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM candidate_tbl ct1 WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT name FROM candidate_tbl ct2 WHERE ct1.name = ct2.name and doneMasters = 'true'
);
```

**Method-3**

```
SELECT name FROM (SELECT name,group_concat(doneMasters) as dmf FROM candidate_tbl
GROUP BY name) dd
WHERE dmf = 'false,false';
```

**Method-4**

```
SELECT name FROM (SELECT name, group_concat(doneMasters) as dmf FROM candidate_tbl
GROUP BY name) dd
WHERE dmf = 'false,false';
```

I want to know which is the best solution in terms of performance and accuracy, or other alternate solutions.

Comment: You need to test the results on your system and on your data.

Comment: If you start storing all the things a candidate hasn't done, this is going to be a HUGE dataset

Comment: Note that queries against views in MySQL are unlikely to be efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Your data model doesn't really make sense to me.  Why store negative information in a table, for instance?

The best way would be to normalize the data model to have a separate table of candidates and their degrees.  Then use `not exists`:

```
select c.*
from candidates c
where not exists (select 1
                  from candidate_degrees cd
                  where cd.candidate_id = c.candidate_id and
                        cd.degree in ('MS', 'MBA')
                 );
```

This would be a rather dramatic change to your data model:

- The degrees table would only have degrees that exist (and perhaps other information such as the year, school, and so on).
- The candidates would be identified by an id that can be used for joining.

Comment: agree with you, actually this is a view where unwanted data is filtered from a table and only this much info is relevant for me

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SELECT name FROM candidate_tbl 
WHERE doneMasters = 'false' 
AND degree in ('MBA', 'MS') 
GROUP BY name HAVING count(1) = 2;
```

DEMO HERE: [**DB-FIDDLE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1485b2e0c46d5a4e56d20fecae4ebbcc)

Answer (score 0):

the solution is simply

```
SELECT name FROM candidate_tbl 
WHERE degree in ('MBA', 'MS') AND doneMasters = 'false' 
GROUP BY name;
```

it will return a unique name from list who has not done MBA or MS.

Answer (score 0):

If for each `name` there are always exactly 2 rows with values `'MBA'` and `'MS'` in the column `degree`, then there is no reason to check or filter the column `degree`.
The simplest way is to group by name, filter out the rows with `true` in the column `doneMasters` and check in the `HAVING` clause if in the results there are 2 rows (these 2 rows will contain `'false'` in the column `doneMasters`):

```
SELECT name
FROM candidate_tbl
WHERE doneMasters = 'false'
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=59fecc669017d402eef79a54a72dfee8).
Results:

```
> | name |
> | :--- |
> | C    |
> | E    |
> | G    |
```

---

Note that a *flag* column like `doneMasters` would be better (for clarity, coding simplicity, less storage space and better performance) defined as `BOOLEAN`.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8acda28f9273c3f46d36a579d47e704a).

Comment: Right, If for each name there are always exactly 2 rows with values 'MBA' and 'MS' in the column degree

Comment: @KoustuvChatterjee This is what I see in your sample data.